# kivy app crashing on pressing button in my mobile

Tags: python, android, kivy, adb, buildozer

I have created a kivy app in which we can get list of applications in our mobile so that we can delete unwanted apps from my kivy app. It is working good in PC but, when i install it on my mobile it is displaying the list of applications but when i press the delete button of respective app, kivy app is crashing.

I had also gone through the logcat. For example I want to delete truecaller app through my kivy app. So when i press the delete button of true caller in kivy app it is showing an error in logact i.e

> subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.truecaller ' returned non-zero exit status 255.

- Can anybody know what is the error here?
- Or is there any changes I have to do in my buildozer.spec file?

Comment: You might try adding permissions `REQUEST_DELETE_PACKAGES` and/or `DELETE_PACKAGES`. But I suspect that an ordinary app is not allowed to uninstall apps.

Comment: @JohnAnderson i have tried this ,but again the app is getting crashed when i press the delete button

Comment: Did you follow this [example](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis/#runtime-permissions)?